# Module not found in JavaFX distribution with Gradle

Tags: gradle, javafx, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to build an app distribution using Gradle, but when I try to run the generated binary I get the error:

```
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
 java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.example.fxnew not found
```

I have read some similar questions, and the only solution they give is to move to Maven.

Is it not possible to create a valid app distribution using Gradle?

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.11'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.fxnew'
    mainClass = 'com.example.fxnew.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '19'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}

distributions {
    main {
        distributionBaseName = 'my-name'
    }
}
```

I have too the file `module-info.java` into the folder: `src/main/java` of the project with this content:

```
module com.example.fxnew {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;

    opens com.example.fxnew to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fxnew;
}
```

The app works fine when I run it from the development environment, but the distribution doesn't work.

For the distribution i'm running this command:

```
gradlew clean build
```

And i have this the folder: `distributions` with two files: `my-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.tar` and `my-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` and into these files, two folders: `bin` and `lib`, i have the error described on top of my answer when I try to open the file called `FXNew`.

Comment: jlink does not link automatic modules so I don’t know why you are providing an automatic module name and using a jlink plugin.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of the automatic module name, you should provide a `module-info.java` file for your app.  I think Idea will do this for you if you [use its JavaFX wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

Comment: What is your distribution? A zip created by the JavaFX gradle jlink plugin? Or something else? What is the command line you use to "run the generated binary"?

Comment: @jewelsea I edited the question with some additional info. I created a new project with the wizard and I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what the file `FXNew` is, it is not in your question.  The launcher name is `app`, which is referenced in your jlink setup.  That is what you should be running.

Comment: @jewelsea FXNew is the name of the new project I created. Idea was created a module named FXNew with this folders: `main/com/example/fxnew`. Into the folder `distributions` is nothing about `app`. To avoid confusion I changed `name = 'app'` to `name = 'FXNew'` but the problem persists.

Comment: The plugin creates a zip named in the question: `${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip`.  That zip is the distribution.  Take the zip, and unzip it.  The extracted zip contains the JRE and runtime for your code and libraries.  The launcher is in the `bin` directory extracted from the zip and is named as per your config: `app` or another  name such as `FXNew` if you changed it.  If you run the launcher it should work.  I see you edited the question to remove the automatic module name, that addressed one issue.

Comment: @jewelsea I have done just what you say in your previous comment and that is when I have the module not found error.

Comment: Try this: `gradlew clean jlinkZip`.  That builds a zip of the jlink image, placing it in the `distributions` directory.

Comment: In my testing, `gradlew clean build` does not invoke jlink (at least in my project created by the idea javafx wizard).  Instead, it zips up all of the libraries and creates a script that uses them, assuming that a java runtime is already installed and configured in JAVA_HOME.  This is probably not what you want.  I don't know why that setup doesn't find your module I didn't check that, but you probably don't want it anyway, so I didn't waste time trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @jewelsea Executing this command I'm having the error: *`Execution failed for task ':prepareMergedJarsDir'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Android" (in directory "/var/folders/s1/xpkwsk7s43s67pp6ykc19dp00000gn/T/badass-11497842432758208622"): error=2, No such file or directory`*

Comment: Well, that is a weird message.  I don't know why Android would relate to any of this.  I run the build on OS X 12 and don't get any such exception, it "just works" for me.  Perhaps the badass jlink plugin is incorrectly inferring you to be targeting an Android app for some reason (I'm guessing you are building on some kind of Linux distribution).  You may need to contact the plugin author for assistance.

Comment: @jewelsea I'm working with Mac OSX M1 (Apple Silicon).

Comment: I have Intel silicon, which is perhaps why it works for me and not you.  Maybe the badass jlink plugin is confused and thinks the M1 is an ARM processor for an Android device (I don't know).  Perhaps if you specify [target platforms](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#_methods), you could work around this.  Without target platforms, it will build an M1 distribution on an M1 device (I don't have advice on building cross-platform distributions on the same device using this method).

Comment: Are you using Intellij Idea to build?  Do you have Android Studio installed (now or in the past)?  That message looks like it might be [trying to use a JRE or something that came bundled with Android Studio](https://www.anycodings.com/1questions/240138/android-studio-cannot-run-tests-because-java-cant-be-found).  Perhaps you have a bad JAVA_HOME or something.  I don't really know, as you can tell ;-). Perhaps check you [Gradle JVM settings in Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html) (mine are set to OpenJDK 17.0.2).

Comment: @jewelsea the previous error regarding Android Studio was because `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to the JDK found in the Android Studio folder. I have changed the `JAVA_HOME` to use the Azul JDK, but it still doesn't work, now giving the error: *`command '/Users/myuser/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-17.0.4.1/Contents/Home/bin/jlink' finished with non-zero exit value 1`*. I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: I don't know why `jlink` is terminating abnormally and am not familiar enough with Gradle or the plugin to provide much assistace.  If there are some debug settings for the badass jlink plugin or gradle, you could try switching them on.  With the maven JavaFX plugin, its debug mode outputs the command line it uses to launch jlink, perhaps you can get the gradle badass jlink plugin to do the same,  then you could try running the same command from the command line, perhaps with a verbose mode for jlink and maybe it will give you more info to help troubleshoot your issue.